# Get random numbers in specific ranges given a 'getrand100()' function

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

For getting the random numbers I have a function `getrand100()` which returns a random number in the range of 1-100.

How can I get a random number between ranges **1-20** and **1-200** with the same function?

For 1-20 I can apply:

```
if(num>=1 && num <=20) then accept else reject
```

But what should I do for the **1-200** range?

Comment: Removed the "-1". While the 1-20 problem is quite trivial, the 1-200 covers the more general problem of making a good random generator with a given resolution X by using a source of randomness of resolution Y where X > Y. Not so trivial, im my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would propose

```
1 + getrand100() % 20
```

for the first case (20) and

```
(getrand100()%2)*100 + getrand100()
```

for the latter (200).

Answer (score 5):

In c++:

```
if (getrand100() % 2) return getrand100();
else return getrand100() + 100;
```

Half the time it will return a number in the range 1-100 (the `if` statement) and the other half of the time it will return a number in the range 101-200 (the `else` statement). You could also (as pointed out in the comments) do any similar condition such as `getrand100() <= 50`.

In fact, you could speed up your 1-20 answer by doing:

```
return (getrand100() % 20) + 1;
```

This way, you don't have to keep rejecting out of range solutions.

Comment: @DEVANG No. I'm not adding `getrand100() % 2`. I'm simply using it as a way to split the probability of getting the `1-100` range and the `101-200` range. As I said, you could also use something like `getrand100() <= 50` instead of `getrand100() % 2`.

Comment: yes, it was my mistake, but your answer is good, now i understand it

Answer (score 1):

The following is a generalized [Las Vegas-Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm):

```
getRand(int upperBound){
  if (upperBound <= 1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
  // TODO: If random set should not start at 1, use another parameter as offset
  if (upperBound <= 50) {
    int num = getRand100();
    while (num > 100 - 100 % upperBound) {
      num = getRand100();
    }  
    return num % upperBound + 1;
  } else if (upperBound <= 100) {
    int num = getRand100();
    while (num > upperBound) {
      num = getRand100();
    }  
    return num;
  } else { 
    return getRand(upperBound / 100) * 100 - 100 + getRand(upperBound % 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Java` Something like this would generate a randomNumber in the required range.

```
int maxLimit=85;
Double someNumber = Math.random()*maxLimit;
int randomNumber=random.intValue(); // return a number from 1 to 85
```

In your case you could simply divide your method result by 100, then multiply by the `maxLimit` (20 or 200 )

Answer (score 1):

A general solution in Java.

```
 public static int rand(int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int num = 1;
    do {
          num = num * 100 + getrand100();
    } while (num <= range);
    return min + num % range;
 }
```

Btw writing code on an iPhone isn't easy ;)